# How to add collective.taxonomy taxonomy to SearchableText index?

Tags: plone

I'm using collective.taxonomy and I have a taxonomy called taxonomy_themes.
I use it with it's behavior in my dexterity content type.
There is allready a index called taxonomy_themes, but I need that this field to be searchable via the SearchableText index.

I've read a lot about collective.dexteritytextindexer but I can't made it work with the taxonomy.

Comment: Check Docu: https://github.com/collective/collective.dexteritytextindexer - It works without any issue. I personally use it a lot. Please specify what exactly does not work in your case? Adding the behavior? Search the field?

Comment: Ok, I may be not very clear.
Adding the behavior is ok. But I want to add my taxonomy in the searchableText index. collective.dexteritytextindexer give some hint but there is not Interfaces for my taxonomy that I can use to add it in the searchableText index.

Comment: Well, did you try to mark your field as searchable=true? Check last section in `Usage` --> https://github.com/collective/collective.dexteritytextindexer#usage You're probably in better hands in github issue tracker of the mentioned addon.

Comment: Yes I've tried in my schema to mark it as searchable like dexteritytextindexer.searchable('taxonomy_themes'), but it says : no field named taxonomy_themes. I think I will ask the question to collective.taxonomy directly. Thanks @Mathias